# want to change the color of my horizontal color strip

Tags: css

i have hyper links in a div i want that back ground color of div should change when i hove over those hyper link

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#green").click(function(){ 
        $("#colorstrip").toggleClass('#colorstrip_green');
    )};
```

Comment: post your CSS, using the `click` event in javascript or jquery is different to using `a:hover` in CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
#colorstrip:hover { background-color:green; }
```

Comment: hi 

Please try to understand my question 

I have horizontal color strip whose color is black.in this horizontal strip i have menu bar like 'green, red, and yellow so i want when i click on these hyper link back ground color of my div should change accordingly..like if i click on green it should change to green..as so on

thanks

Comment: Your original question specifically said you wanted to change when you hover over a link.

If I understand you correctly, then your original code is nearly correct.  It should be .toggleClass("colorstrip_green")   , without the "#" 
And, of course, you will need to have that class defined:   .colorstrip_green { background-color:green; }